# React Native how to change image source with crossfade animation?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 different images that I want to loop between. **When the image source changes, I want to apply a crossfade transition**. Right now, it changes the background every 5 seconds as I want to, however, **it does not transition with a crossfade effect**

I have tried using [LayoutAnimation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/layoutanimation.html), but it does not work for this.

I am using [Expo](https://expo.io/) if that matters.

First off, I have two images that I'm using

```
import BackgroundeOne from '../../Images/login-background1-tint.jpg'
import BackgroundeTwo from '../../Images/login-background2.jpg'
```

I have an array of my images

```
 var backgrounds = [BackgroundeOne, BackgroundeTwo]
```

In my state, I have my current background

```
 this.state = { background: BackgroundeOne }
```

I have a function that sets the state

```
 changeBackground = () => {
    let currentBg = this.state.background
    let newIndex = backgrounds.indexOf(currentBg) + 1   
    let newBg = (newIndex) == backgrounds.length ? backgrounds[0] : backgrounds[newIndex] 


    this.setState({
        background: newBg
    })
}
```

I start an intervall repeat calling this function every 5 seconds

```
componentDidMount() { 
setInterval( () => { 
        this.changeBackground()
     }, 5000);
}
```

And finally, I have an Image component

```
<Image source={this.state.background} />
```

**How can I change the source with a crossfade animation?**

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the lifecycle method componentWillUpdate. As stated in the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate):

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new
>   props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to
>   perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called
>   for the initial render.

so if you define this method on your component like this:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

You still have access to your current state using this.state and you can see what your new source will be using nextState. Inside this method you should put your logic to make the animation perform what your want.

Comment: Thank you, but will this be of help even though I am setting the state and getting the image from the current state? It is changing the background, but the animation does not apply. I am a little lost of what I should place inside of componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: Sorry, then your lifecycle method should be componentWillUpdate, I'll update my answer!

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help. It says I cannot use setState in componentWillUpdate, but I did try to use

LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutSpring);

Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.. I'm not sure what to do in componentWillUpdate..

Comment: To do a crossFade animation you should create an Animated value to control the opacity style prop of your component, you will need two animations, and two backgrounds one overlapping the other. Then you make one disappear and the other appear using Animation.timing